# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError : com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.ClientTubeAssemblerContext.getPortInfo()Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/client/WSPortInfo;

Tags: java, web-services, apache-flex

I want to call webservice from flex3. Webservice works as util jar without fault but ı can't run it from flex. It gives the following error

```
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError : com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.ClientTubeAssemblerContext.getPortInfo()
Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/client/WSPortInfo;:null error.
```

Any idea how to resolve it?

Comment: where do you get this error on? the client? or the server? post some code please for us to understand what you are doing. Thanks.

Comment: client. user will give identification number and then webservice return detailed info about it on flex screen. it worked as jar but did not work in flex.

Comment: Can you post the code as how you are trying to call the WS?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add correct version of library file.
jaxws-rt-2.2.5.jar file contain the required method com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.ClientTubeAssemblerContext.getPortInfo().
Test adding above mentioned library.